# Logging out a user from the site

Tags: asp.net

I was adding login and logout functionality to my ASP.NET website. While I am able to make the user log in by checking the username and password but on some pages should be available only if he is logged in. I am doing this by storing the user's value in a session

Secondly, I am using a `Link button` which changes to `Logged in as example`. So, how does the user log out?

Comment: Are you asking for recommendations for a logout UI element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You kill the session:

```
Session.Abandon();
```

Comment: When the user is logged in, the link button's functionality should change to anoother event for doing this. How do I do that?

Comment: Don't change the event - that will still be LinkButton1_Click.  You need to if(Session != null){Session.Abandon();}

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 server side LinkButtons on your page and have their visibility be mutually exclusive.

```
LoginLinkButton.Visible = ....;
LogoutLinkButton.Visible = !LoginLinkButton.Visible
```

Answer (score 0):

You might spend a look at [ASP.NET Login Controls Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx)

Two ways to logout a user are:

1. The user clicks on the autogenerated Logout Button of the LoginStatus control
2. The manually abandon the session in the codebehind

Use this snippet:

```
   Session.Abandon();
   System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

---

About this whole visibility thing based upon the current login state, you can use [LoginView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx), which is exactly what you are looking for, instead of manually assigning the Visibility property as Babak Naffas suggested